# Bing web search with Azure - I can't get my command to work ? (invalid endpoint)

Tags: azure

I'm trying to make use of the **Microsoft Azure Search API** to do some searches internally. The `curl` example on https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/f40197291cd14401b93a478716e818bf/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d is:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=bill%20gates&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate"
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}"

--data-ascii "{body}"
```

So I'm trying:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=steampunk+junkies&count=25&mkt=en-GB" \
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: my-sub-key" \
--data-ascii "{body}"
```

(I've removed my subscription-key obviously :))

This gives me an error message:

```
{"error":{"code":"401","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."}}
```

Here is what I have setup:

[image]

And this is what I see when I click on the subscription:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems that it requires a non trial subscription.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio hmm thats a bit stupid if they are offering you "£150 free credits" to test out their system before paying ;/

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio mmm nope, even with a PAYG subscription it still won't work. Must be something to do with the endpoint as the subscription id is correct :/

Comment: I've contacted support and will see what they come back with. I'll reply here once I find out :)

Comment: it worked in here... it must be your subscription

Answer (score 1):

I've just did a test using https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/f40197291cd14401b93a478716e818bf/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d/console

and it's working fine:

```
GET https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=bill gates&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate HTTP/1.1
Host: api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

response:

```
BingAPIs-TraceId: 4E8D0A11EE2247CD88B488A19BD3DC03
BingAPIs-SessionId: D15F683F4D0348DB9063D1DDBCA8E3F2
X-MSEdge-ClientID: 13F75314B9C4654320CD5C1AB888642D
X-MSAPI-UserState: aa01
BingAPIs-Market: en-US
X-Search-ResponseInfo: InternalResponseTime=343,MSDatacenter=CO4
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 4E8D0A11EE2247CD88B488A19BD3DC03 Ref B: BY3EDGE0110 Ref C: 2020-07-21T13:43:09Z
apim-request-id: ac1e33dc-851a-41cf-b02f-98521276a969
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
CSP-Billing-Usage: CognitiveServices.BingSearchV7.Transaction=1
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2020 13:43:09 GMT
P3P: CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC CURa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR IND"
Content-Length: 26089
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 21 Jul 2020 13:42:09 GMT

{
  "_type": "SearchResponse",
  "queryContext": {
    "originalQuery": "bill gates"
  },
  "webPages": {
    "webSearchUrl": "https:\/\/www.bing.com\/search?q=bill+gates",
    "totalEstimatedMatches": 2230000,
    "value": [{
      "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.0",
      "contractualRules": [{
        "_type": "ContractualRules\/LicenseAttribution",
        "targetPropertyName": "snippet",
        "targetPropertyIndex": 0,
        "mustBeCloseToContent": true,
        "license": {
          "name": "CC-BY-SA",
          "url": "http:\/\/creativecommons.org\/licenses\/by-sa\/3.0\/"
        },
        "licenseNotice": "Text under CC-BY-SA license"
      }],
      "name": "Bill Gates - Wikipedia",
      "url": "https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Bill_Gates",
      "about": [{
        "name": "Bill Gates"
      }, {
        "name": "Bill Gates"
      }],
      "isFamilyFriendly": true,
      "displayUrl": "https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Bill_Gates",
      "snippet": "Gates and his wife invited Joan Salwen to Seattle to speak about what the family had done, and on December 9, 2010, Bill and Melinda Gates and investor Warren Buffett each signed a commitment they called the \"Giving Pledge\", which is a commitment by all three to donate at least half of their wealth, over the course of time, to charity.",
      "dateLastCrawled": "2020-07-07T17:23:00.0000000Z",
      "language": "en",
      "isNavigational": false
    }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes I get the same error in there using my sub id. I'll wait and see what support tell me. I'm 100% putting in the sub-id they gave me, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work (it doesn't take time to update in their system does it? I know Google API keys can sometimes do that)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing. I've creted the bing search resource on my azure subscription and that's all. I even selected free tier to test, so it must be something in your azure subscription. You'd better wait for the support

Comment: OK so the problem was that I was using mt subscription-id (on the "Subscriptions" page), but I should have been using value in "All Resources > my app > keys and endpoints > key 1 + the endpoint). They should probably update their article a bit to make it clearer its not he "subscription id" you need to pass, but the "key" for your app!